# On curves lying on a smooth projective surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve lying on a smooth projective surface $X$, Let $K_X, K_C$ are canonical bundles over $X$ and $C$. Then one can consider the sequence $$0 \to \mathcal O_X(-C) \to \mathcal O_X \to j_{*}(\mathcal O_C) \to 0$$

where $j: C \to X$ is the inclusion and $j_{*}$ is the pushforward functor (please correct me if this is wrong).

Let us tensor it with $K_X$ and assume that $h^i(\mathcal O_X(-C) \otimes K_X)=0$ for $i=0,1$ Then by projection formula we have, $h^0(X, K_X)=h^0(X, j_{*}(\mathcal O_C) \otimes K_X)=h^0(X, j_{*}(K_X|_C))$. My confusion is that : is it somehow elementary to identify  the last term as $h^0(C, K_X|_C)$?

And assuming that $K_X$ is ample and globally generated, do we have, under the cohomology vanishing hypothesis : $h^0(X, K_X)=h^0(C, K_X|_C)$ and $h^1(X, K_X) \geq h^1(C, K_X|_C)$?

Comment: It is elementary: follows by definition of $ H^0 $ and even in general, $ H^i $ are the same because $ j $ is a closed immersion, in particular affine, so pushforward is exact. Which means that $ h^1(X, K_X) \le h^1(C, K_X|_C) $ under your hypothesis and the obstruction to equality is given by $ h^2(X, O_X(-C) \otimes K_X) = h^0(X, O_X(C)) $ which is non-zero. So what you write for $ h^1 $ is false.

Comment: @CraniumClamp, Thank you. I think we then have the following: $h^i(X, j_{*}(\mathcal O_C) \otimes K_X)=h^i(X, j_{*}(K_X|_C))=h^i(C, K_X|_C)$ for all $i$, but equality with $h^0(X, K_X)$ holds only when $i=0$ (please correct me if this is not what you meant).

Comment: Yes, I meant your inequality. The equality of $ h^0 $ is obviously correct under your hypothesis.